# Javascript analog Clock Hour Hand Is Not Working while the other hands are

Tags: javascript

I have an analog clock built with a bit of javascript code. The second hand and the minute hand are working perfectly, however, the hour hand is not functioning. Can anyone see why?

```
const deg = 6;
const degHR = 30;
const hr = document.querySelector("#hr");
const mn = document.querySelector("#mn");
const sc = document.querySelector("#sc");
setInterval(() => {
        let day = new Date();
        let hh = day.getHours() * degHR;
        let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
        let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;
        hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${hh+(mm/12)} deg)`;
        mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
        sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getHours()` method returns hours in 24h format. Probably you want to adapt the corresponding lines as follows:

```
    let hh = ((day.getHours() % 12) + day.getMinutes()/60) * degHR;
    let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
    let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;
    hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${hh}deg)`;
    mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
    sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
```

Especially notice the removed space before `deg`!

Comment: Thanks... Still no luck with.

Comment: Maybe you can give some more information about what is wrong with the hour hand. Is it moving too slow?

Comment: I haven't had it running for an hour yet, but it is starting at the 12 o'clock position rather than the actual time.

Comment: I think your rotateZ transformation is also off. I edited my answer.

Comment: It probably starts at the 12 o'clock position because the transformation is not correctly applied. You need to remove the space before the deg unit.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect because it's the only one with a fractional number of degrees. Try changing `(mm/12)` to `Math.round(mm/12)`.

Comment: I gave it a shot with hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${hh+Math.round(mm/12)} deg)`; with the same result.